# How to decrease memory usage when passing big variables around

Tags: php, variables, memory

For example:

```
a(wordwrap(str_repeat('abcdef', 500000), 160, "\n", true));    

function a($v){
  $v[1] = 'x';      
  $v = b($v);
  return $v;
}

function b($v){
  $v[2] = 'x';    
  $v = c($v);
  return $v;
}

function c($v){
  $v[3] = 'x';  
  d($v);    
}

function d($v){
  $v[4] = 'x';
  print $v;
}
```

This uses ~23 MB. I think because PHP is creating a copy of that text on each modification.
If I just print the text once it uses 12 MB.

Can I somehow free the memory for the original variable before functions are called? Like

```
unset($v);
$v = c($v);
```

Obviously this won't work because `$v` is destroyed before it gets passed to `c()` lol. But I'd like to somehow let `c()` modify the same text. Like using references. (I tried references but they actually increase memory usage, probably because PHP makes more copies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, PHP uses copy-on-write approach. You might wanna try references, e.g.:

```
function a(&$v){
    $v[1] = 'x';      
    $v = b($v);
    return $v;
}
```

I just noticed, that you tried references, are you sure that memory usage wasn't lower?

Comment: strangely it is for the code I posted above, but it's higher for the real code on which I'm working :(

Comment: Probably, you are missing some important part, which uses up memory in real code? Is it too big/complex/shareware to post here?